# Copy folder from an http source to a local directory

Tags: ruby

I am trying to copy a folder from an http source using the following statement:

```
FileUtils.cp_r 'http://else.repository.labs/static/lit/MDMInternalTools/', 'c:\Users\Public\Desktop\'
```

However I get this error:

```
EINVAL: Invalid argument - https://else.repository.labs/static/lit/MDMInternalTools/
```

Comment: I know it might be hard to imagine for people those days but Internet is not a filesystem...

Comment: You cannot *copy* folders via http like that. You have to *download* each file individual. If that folder is under your controll, it might be easier to zip it on the server and download the zip file. Or if it is some kind of repository then there might be the option to clone that repository.

Answer (score 0):

If that's a folder on a server that you have access to via ssh, then you can use `scp` to copy individual files, or a folder with all subfolders/files, using the `-r` option.  The command will be something like

```
scp -r username@http://else.repository.labs:/path/to/rails/public/static/lit/MDMInternalTools c:\Users\Public\Desktop
```

This is assuming you can use scp.  It looks like you're in windows, you'll need a decent command-line shell where you can install ssh.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the server supports webdav, have an ftp or an ssh access.
Otherwise your only choice could be to use wget to get a local mirror:

```
 wget -mk http://else.repository.labs/static/lit/MDMInternalTools/
```